# Crash when running C# app with CPP\CLR on windows server 2012

Tags: c#, c++, clr, windows-server-2012

I am using CLR to run a pre-compiled dll from C++ in a C# environment and experiencing differences between win server 2012 and win 7\win server 2008.

While in windows 7 or windows server 2008 the program works fine, but when trying to run in server 2012 I get:

"dll or one of its dependencies is not a valid win32 application"

Any known issues\solutions to this problem?

(OS is always 64, .net 4.5, VS 2013)

(Attached picture show the dll in Dependency walker under both OS)

[Dependency walker on Windows server 2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mozv3.png)

[Dependency walker on Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCyLJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the C++ run-time libraries on your server. Specificly, from the file name `MSVCP100D.DLL` I can tell that you need the *debug version* of the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable", which is *not* allowed to be redestributed (as opposed to the release version which you can find [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555))

You can find the debug version of the run-time library inside the Visual Studio 2010 folder in the `VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist` folder. (Disclaimer: I don't have 2010 installed, but 2013 and 2015) As a workaround you can copy the missing dlls to the same folder you have your dll in.

To prevent having this problem in the future, either get a non-debug version of the DLL and install the public runtime redistributable or compile a static build (which includes those libraries in the DLL thus making it larger), debug or not.

Comment: Whats  the difference between windows 7 & server 2008 to Server 2012?

Comment: @Daniel In this case probably that you have VS 2010 installed on one but not the other. Installing VS installs the debug run-time libraries on the system.